# My own module will not import to python 3.8

Tags: python, module, importerror, python-3.8

I'm going through a 4 hour beginner course for python and I get to a section of pip and modules. The first step is to make my own module, simple enough. This is called `useful_tools.py` and the code looks like this:

```
import random

feet_in_mile = 5280
meters_in_kilometer = 1000
beatles = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Star"]


def get_file_ext(filename):
    return filename[filename.index(".") + 1:]


def roll_dice(num):
    return random.randint(1, num)
```

This runs great. So now I go to my other .py program and go to import so I can run my own module inside the other .py
That code looks like this:

```
import useful_tools

print(useful_tools.roll_dice(10))
```

I still get an error on the import line of code saying "no module named useful_tools"

The `useful_tools.py` file is in the exact same directory as the rest of my files so its not across other folders.

Edit: I am able to access all the information from that file however there is no drop down list of the functions from the `useful_tools.py` and it will still throw the error of "no module named..." how do I resolve that error and get that drop down list?

Comment: Sorry I know this looks like a stupid question, but just to be sure, you python file is called useful_tools.py and not tools.py, and that both files are saved in the same folder?

Comment: You need an __init__.py file in order to create a module, then you would usually wrap both the source and the init file in a folder with the name of your module.

Comment: Flavio, Yes, I had just short handed the last part but edited it for better clarification. the file I'm trying to import to is called "pip and modules.py" the pip and modules.py file is in the same folder as the useful_tools.py.

Comment: Just for test, comment the `import useful_tools` and try `from os import listdir` then `print(listdir))`. Did you see `useful_tools.py` in the printed list?

Comment: Flavio, yes it is in that list